# VueJS - DOM template parsing and custom elements

Tags: javascript, templates, vue.js, dom

basically I need VueJS to warn me about unregistered components when in DOM template parsing mode. It currently looks like Vue is not caring about custom HTML when using DOM templates, meanwhile errors are correctly issued when using single-file components, string templates and x-templates (as per [the docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#DOM-Template-Parsing-Caveats)).

One simple way to reproduce the issue is to register a component:

```
Vue.component('existing', {
  template: `
    <div>
      <p>Existing component</p>
    </div>
  `
})
```

and then mount a simple Vue instance

```
new window.Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      text: 'text'
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    console.log('mounted')
  }
})
```

where, in the DOM under the `#app` element, there is an unregistered element, as in

```
<div id="app">
  {{text}}
  <existing></existing>

  <!-- Should give an error -->
  <non-existing></non-existing>
</div>
```

I've prepared a [CodePen](https://codepen.io/ibanjo/pen/vwExdL) to reproduce this simple environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vue does throw a `[Vue warn]` error in this case.

However, you're using a production build of Vue in your CodePen example (`vue.min.js`), which suppresses these warnings.

Here's an example using a non-production build of Vue:

```js
Vue.config.devtools = false;

Vue.component('existing', {
  template: `
    <div>
      <p>Existing component</p>
    </div>
  `
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      text: 'text'
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    console.log('root mounted')
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  {{text}}
  <existing></existing>
  
  <!-- Should give an error -->
  <non-existing></non-existing>
</div>
```

Comment: Actually that was (trivially) it. Thank you!